# Change value of form input before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I've got a `PayPal` button.

```
<form method="post" action= "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mail@gmail.com">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item name">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1234">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value=0>
   <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
   <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

When I press on this button, I need to change value of `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value=0>` and only then submit. How to do that?

Comment: Isnt it already 0? And are you trying to do this on your page or someother's site?

Comment: On my page, I need to change it, because the price at that page can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(form).submit(function(){
    $('[name=amount]').val(0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using jquery selector as shown below

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  $("input[name='amount']").val();
})
```